# SwiftUI AppDelegate UIWindow redeclaration

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate

I'm using SwiftUI so the AppDelegate is added by

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(MyAppDelegate.self) var myAppDelegate
```

All delegate callbacks work fine, but `var window: UIWindow?` can't be redeclared.

Adding it to `MyAppDelegate` has no effect as if accessing `UIApplication.shared.delegate` class is not `MyAppDelegate` but `SwiftUI.AppDlegate`.

How I can add it to AppDelegate, to make it accessible by `UIApplication.shared.delegate.window` ?

Or how to set `var window: UIWindow?` property to `SwiftUI.AppDlegate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. Custom `MyAppDelegate` can contain `var window: UIWindow?` property:

```
class MyAppDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

}
```

And can be accessed by `EnvironmentVariable`:

```
@EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: MyAppDelegate

appDelegate.window = <Window object>
```

Then the correct `UIWindow` value will be available by `UIApplication.shared.delegate.window`

Documentation refference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiapplicationdelegateadaptor